# How to call anonymous function (Closure) from inline object?

Tags: php

I need to quickly mock an object, so that when in template appears:

```
$that->user->isAdmin()
```

it will return `true`.

I tried to cast an array with anonymous function into object:

```
$that = (object) ( (array(
    'user'      =>
        (object) (array(
            'isAdmin' => function() {
                return true;
            }
(...)
```

but `var_dump($that->user)` returns an empty(?) Closure:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["isAdmin"]=>
  object(Closure)#2 (1) {
    ["this"]=>
    object(View)#1 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

and calling it directly by `$that->user->isAdmin()` returns `Call to undefined method stdClass::isAdmin()`.

How can I rewrite `$that` in order to be able to call `$that->user->isAdmin()`? 

Can be done in a dirty/hacky way, since it's only for a mocking purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$that->user->isAdmin` is a propriety of the `$that->user` object, that's also a Closure. If you try to call it with `$that->user->isAdmin()`, you are trying to call the *method* `isAdmin` instead.

From php7 you can call it with

```
$bool = ($that->user->isAdmin)();
```

Otherwhise you can put `$that->user->isAdmin` in a variable and call it, or use `call_user_func` instead.

**EDIT**

If you want a *method* `isAdmin`:

```
$that = (object) ( (array(
    'user' => new class {
        public function isAdmin() {
            return true;
        }
    })
));

$bool = $that->user->isAdmin();
```

Comment: The tricky part is that it has to be called precisely by `$that->user->isAdmin()`, because it's a mock. I can only change `$that` object.

Comment: then you don't need a closure, you need a method with that name

Comment: regarding your edit - is this construct from PHP7 as well? because I get `unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)`